# How to know the value of built-in macro in RPM?

Tags: linux, packaging, rpm

How do I view the value of these macros in RPM? I can take a guess that %_bindir is /usr/bin, %_tmppath is /tmp, but: how exactly do I view these values and are their values system-dependent?

```
%_prefix 
%_exec_prefix 
%_bindir 
%_sbindir 
%_libexecdir 
%_datadir 
%_sysconfdir 
%_sharedstatedir 
%_localstatedir 
%_libdir 
%_includedir 
%_oldincludedir
%_infodir 
%_mandir 
/usr 
%{_prefix) 
%{_exec_prefixl/bin 
%{_exec_prefix}/sbin 
%{_exec_prefix}/libexec 
%{_prefixJ/share 
%{_prefix}/etc 
%{_prefixJ/com 
%{_prefix}/var 
%{_exec_prefix}/lib 
%{_prefix}/include 
/usr/include 
%{_prefix}/info 
%{_prefixl/man
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the `--eval` switch:

```
$ rpm --eval '%{_rpmdir}'
/usr/src/redhat/RPMS
```

Answer (score 17):

The `--showrc` option...

```
rpm --showrc
```

...will dump the complete `rpmrc` to stdout.  This will expose all sorts of interest definitions from the innards of RPM.  But Corey's answer is better for finding the value of a particular symbol.